# Can't get cross-domain getJSON calls to work on Internet Explorer, works fine on Firefox, and works on single domain for both IE and Firefox

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, cross-domain, jsonp, getjson

I am having a really weird problem, I am using .getJSON to another url, I have added

```
Header add Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*"
```

into my page to allow the cross-domain JSONP calls. All works fine on firefox but when I use IE it does not, the script works fine when working on only 1 domain, but when making the calls from another domain, the result doesnt seem to get returned at all.

Is there something blocking it that might be browser specific? If so, is there any way around this?

```
    $.getJSON(url + "controller.php?suppliesfinderaction=getModelBrands", function (results) {
                if(results.result == 1) {
                    setOptions($brand, results.data, "brand", "brand");
                    $brand.attr("disabled", false);
                } else {
                    setErrors($this, results['errors']);
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to add 'callback=?' to your url's query string for Jsonp to work.